# Running dcm4chee on a docker enviroment on Ubuntu

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, dcm4che

I am trying to do a quick run of dcm4chee arc 5 on docker. Following the docker-compose approach, all other containers are running except for the slapd container exiting with the error below.

docker logs **0d68b878d4c1** 
65d5b730.28f21c6a 0x7f22ef1b9b48 @(#) $OpenLDAP: slapd 2.6.5 (Jul 11 2023 03:35:58) $
openldap
65d5b730.298966cc 0x7f22ef1b9b48 lt_dlopenext failed: (back_hdb) file not found
65d5b730.298a6cbd 0x7f22ef1b9b48 olcModuleLoad: value #0:  handler exited with 1!
65d5b730.298af5f0 0x7f22ef1b9b48 config error processing cn=module{0},cn=config:  handler exited with 1
65d5b730.298ff7c9 0x7f22ef1b9b48 slapd stopped.
65d5b730.29910cd8 0x7f22ef1b9b48 connections_destroy: nothing to destroy.

Tried checking out the back_hdb file they are talking about but could not get it clearly.

here are relevant links:
https://github.com/dcm4che/dcm4chee-arc-light/wiki/Running-on-Docker
https://github.com/dcm4che-dockerfiles/slapd-dcm4chee